# std::copy или copy_s?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio 2013 советует не использовать `std::copy` настолько настоятельно, что считает это за ошибку, а не предупреждение. Порывшись и поспрашивав, нашел _Copy_s, на который, наверно, ссылается VS. Но я так и не разобрался, как на него перейти. Исходная строчка:`std::copy(octx->pos, octx->pos + count,buf);` 
Еще VS на попытку вызвать basic_string::_Copy_s говорит, что must be a class or namespace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa985872%28v=vs.120%29.aspx Буду благодарен за решение с объяснением.

Comment: Ошибка в другом, покажите весь код. Точнее, покажите ошибку, а также что такое `octx->pos` и `buf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, раньше в VC++ существовала функция `copy_s`, но в последних версиях VC++ ее убрали, видимо потому что остальные компиляторы ее не поддерживают. (`_Copy_s` это внутренняя часть реализации стандартной библиотеки, не надо пытаться ее использовать.)

Для того чтобы использовать `std::copy` в VC++ можно воспользоваться одним из следующих вариантов:

1. Компилировать с `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Это отключает все предупреждения для небезопасных функций.
2. Использовать адаптер `checked_array_iterator` или `unchecked_array_iterator`:

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <iterator>

   int main() {
     int* a = new int[5]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
     int* b = new int[5];
     std::copy(a, a + 5, stdext::make_checked_array_iterator(b, 5));
     std::copy(a, a + 5, stdext::make_unchecked_array_iterator(b));
     delete[] a;
     delete[] b;
   }
   ```

Comment: А что за проблема с `std::copy`?

Comment: а, думал, что-то новое. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

А ещё можно снять флажок SDL при создании проекта.

PS: http://www.cyberforum.ru/post5487819.html

Comment: #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS помогло собрать проект, но предупреждение все-равно показывается.